# Как включить режим редактирования полигона в yandex map 3.0?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть ли такая фича в версии 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В API 3.0 нет редактора полигонов. Если появится позднее, его добавят в документацию.